# How to center and flush right cells in a column

Tags: pdftex, r, markdown

I am trying to create a table with a numeric column `number` which I wish to **center** and **flushright** content as follows:

[image]

Using RMarkdown, I am only able to wrap `LaTeX` code around/inline with cell content in R using the `paste0()` as follows, and I am not able to modify the `LaTeX tabular` environment:

i.e. `table$number <- paste0("\\begin{centering}", table$number, "\\end{centering})`

So possible ways to approach this is to use `eqmakebox` or `multicol` or `varwidth`. But my surficial understanding of these commands have not made possible of what I want.

The table in `LaTeX` as a reproducible example:

```
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {>{\centering}X>{\raggedleft}X}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{name} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{number}\\
\hline
a & 10\\           % please only make
\hline
bb & 193048\\      % edits in these 
\hline
ccc & 200\\        % lines so I can reproduce in R
\hline
\end{tabu}
```

[SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366429/how-to-center-flushed-right-column-text-in-kable) with more flavours of R in it

Comment: What about changing each table line to `a & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10}\\ `, i.e. using `table$number <- paste0("\multicolumn{1}{c}{", table$number, "}")` Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: mwe]

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
---

\tabcolsep3em

```{r,echo=F}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(name=c("a","bb","ccc"), number=c(10,193048,200))
kable(df,"latex", align="lr", booktabs = T, linesep = "") %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  column_spec(1, width = "3em") %>%
  column_spec(2, width = "3em")
```

```{r,echo=F,results='asis'}
library(xtable)
options(xtable.comment = F)
print(xtable(df,digits=0,align="llr"), include.rownames=F,booktabs=T)
```
````

Comment: Thank you @Fran. I was able to center the ‘Number’ column with Kable package. However, any idea how to also flush right the numbers? (As seen in the image from the post) And that is great you are using Kable method as I’ve written lots of codes in kableExtra package and hope not to switch package

Comment: @Jane Answer changed. Is it ok now?

Comment: that is beautiful thank you! Would you be OK if I answer the same question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366429/how-to-center-flushed-right-column-text-in-kable) with your method? Alternatively, I'll let you post and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Jane You're welcome. Feel free to answer yourself the other question.

Comment: what is your insight on columns with long names, with the column width specification, the long names get squished -- Is there a way I can only customise the rows below the columns? There is no `width` argument in `row_spec()`. If not, this is already great!

Comment: @Jane Try `colnames(df) <- c("A very long name","A very long number")` ater define the data frame  and you will see that the text is wrapped in `kable` but not in `xtable`. For  xtable  you can use `align="lp{3em}p{3em}"` and then both tables are equally wrapped (note that here you must align 3 columns in spite that row names are not showed. Note also that you cannot define  `p` columns in this way in kable)